# Can I use the camelCase of a TypeName as the variable name in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Coming from a C# and JavaScript background I am accustomed to variable declarations for complex types like this:

```
//C# example
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter();
```

I have inherited a number of VB.Net projects from another part of my company and have to maintain code that looks like this:

```
'VB.Net example
Using SW As New StreamWriter(Path + "\source.txt")
     Dim W As New CsvWriter(SW, ",")
     ' additional code snipped
End Using
```

For several reasons as I add features to this codebase I would like to rename those variables to a style similar to I and the rest of the team use for C#. So the code would look like:

```
Using streamWriter As New StreamWriter(Path + "\source.txt")
    Dim csvWriter As New CsvWriter(streamWriter, ",")
    ' additional code snipped
End Using
```

I know that VB.Net is "case-insensitive" when it comes to variable names, so that:

```
Dim someVariable as String
Dim SomeVariable as String
```

results in a warning that "Local variable SomeData is already declared in the current block".

But what I don't know is **am I running a risk or violating some common convention by using the camelCase version of the type as my variable name as I would in C#?** Like:

```
Dim cvsWriter as CvsWriter
```

Is there something in the standard or implications for CLS compliance that implies I should or should not use this convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something in the standard or implications for CLS compliance that implies I should or should not use this convention?

There is [this guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions#case-sensitivity):

> Languages that can run on the CLR are not required to support case-sensitivity, although some do. Even if your language supports it, other languages that might access your framework do not. Any APIs that are externally accessible, therefore, cannot rely on case alone to distinguish between two names in the same context.
>
> **X DO NOT** assume that all programming languages are case sensitive. They are not. Names cannot differ by case alone.

The important bit here is **by case alone**.

In

```vb
Using streamWriter As New StreamWriter(Path + "\source.txt")
```

, the two `streamWriter`s are not different by the case alone, they are also different in their scope. As long as there is something else that distinguishes the names (such as scope), you are not violating the rule.

In contrast, if you were to declare this enum in C#:

```cs
public enum Wtf
{ 
    yes,
    no,
    Yes,
    No
}
```

, it would work in C#, but you would not be able to use it properly from e.g. VB, because it defines multiple names in the same scope that are different by case alone.

(I have seen an example of this in PayPal API. It was impossible to use it from VB without editing the automatically generated wrapper code.)

So when you declare a variable of your own to hold an instance of a class, you can name the variable after that class, you can use whatever case you want, and it should not break anything (and if it does, *that something* is not CLS-compliant).

What you should not do is create a *publicly visible* entity where *otherwise equal* members only differ by case, such as two properties of a class or two members of an enum.

Comment: Be careful. The `Using` keyword creates a lexical scope in which the instance is defined, and is unavailable outside of it. So you can have `streamWriter` and `StreamWriter` in successive `Using` blocks, but not in successive `Dim`s. In this way it differs from C# (you could have declared them in successive `var`s without error). Heck, both examples could be named with identical letters and case, and would compile. Note in VB.NET if your variable is named the same as the class (case-insensitive) you can't easily access static members without fully-qualifying the class name.

Comment: @djv I did not mean to use both *lines*. I meant that `StreamWriter` within *either* of the lines does not cause problems regardless of case.

Comment: ok. I felt the question was more about lexical scoping similarly named variables which differ by case because of the message OP pasted "Local variable SomeData is already declared in the current block", where C# would allow it, and VB.NET would not. With Using blocks you would avoid that issue and it made me think your answer misses the point somewhat.

Comment: Truth is, I'm not sure this answers the question. I know the problems of using Dim someName and Dim SomeName (or the same structure with Using) and lexical scope. Specifically, I am wondering if using Dim employee as Employee or Dim cvsWriter as CvsWriter, or any other differently-cased variation of the TypeName is problematic. In other words does "Names cannot differ by case alone." mean that Dim cvsWriter as CvsWriter is bad practice?

Comment: @Gary.Ray You are right, and I have edited my answer.